# How does this "if" function works?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def foo(num,base):
    if(num >= base):
        foo(num // base, base)
    print(num%base)
```

The outcome of foo(2,2) will be
1
0

I can't figure out how this function work?
Could you please advise me about this?

Comment: Please do some research about *recursion*.

Answer (score 0):

Its recursion,

First you are calling foo(2,2)
within the same function you are calling foo(1,2)
which is printing 1.

then it goes back to the earlier function that is foo(2,2).
which again prints 2%2 i.e 0